# How to access inline data in django ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I need to process a file uploaded in a django admin form.  I've added a file upload field to the form:

```
class ExampleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OtherExample
    extra = 1
class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    filedata = forms.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
class ExampleModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ExampleForm
    inlines = [ExampleInline,]
```

This renders the form exactly like I want it to render.  The data returned in Request is exactly what I expect.

The issue is that I want to access the contents of the inline.

```
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...
def save_model(self, Request, obj, form, change):
   the_file = form.cleaned_data['filedata']
   # do amazing things to contents of file
```

At this point I want to reference the results of what the user selected in the inline.  Whatever they picked for OtherExample.

How do I access that through the form?  I would prefer not to go through the Request but am willing to do that.  I'm also willing to examine `save_related(self,request, form, formset, change)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`save_related` can do this, although it's called after the form is saved so you'll end up saving the object twice. You can access the object as `form.instance` or `formset.instance`.

```
def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    obj = form.instance
    # whatever your formset dependent logic is to change obj.filedata
    obj.save()
    super(ExampleAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
```

Comment: Thank you, I had sort of gotten to the must use `save_related` but where is `OtherExample` in the `formset`?

Comment: If you're reading data from the inline formset, you probably want to look in the `cleaned_data` dict for each of its forms. Or fully override the built in `save_related` and `save_formset` so you can capture the results of saving the formset, which will be the changed or created `OtherExample` instances.

Comment: that was it: `formset[0].cleaned_data` holds the data I need in `save_related()`.  Thank you